# Aspect by method annotation not being executed

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop, spring-aop

I am trying to create an aspect to monitor the time execution of certain methods. I define the annotation as:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(
{
    ElementType.METHOD, 
    ElementType.TYPE
})
public @interface TimePerformance {

}
```

And this is the aspect code:

```
@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(timePerformance)")
    public Object  timePerformance(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp,TimePerformance timePerformance) throws Throwable {

        if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
             LOG.info("AOP - Before executing "+pjp.getSignature());
        }

        Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Object result = pjp.proceed();

        Long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        LOG.info("MONITOR TIME_EXECUTION "+pjp.getSignature()+" : "+(stopTime-startTime));

        if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
             LOG.info("AOP - After  executing "+pjp.getSignature());
        }

        return result;

    }
```

And the configuration is:

```
<!-- AOP support -->
<bean id='stateAspectImpl' class='eu.genetwister.snpaware.ui.aspect.StateAspectImpl' />
 <bean id='monitorImpl' class='eu.genetwister.snpaware.monitor.MonitorImpl' />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    <aop:include name='stateAspectImpl' />
     <aop:include name='monitorImpl' />
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
```

I have been annotated a method (part of a spring batch job) like this:

```
@BeforeStep
    @TimePerformance
    public void retrieveInterstepData(StepExecution stepExecution)
```

But the aspect is never being executed, even if the method is executed.

Does anyone an idea about how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the execution(..) in the pointcut expression? I believe    @Around(value = @annotation(<full name of the class including the package>)") should work.

Comment: Using your approach @Around("value = @annotation(<path>.TimePerformance)") gives an exception about an error in the format

Comment: can you mention the exception? What does it say? It might be that the Aspect isnt a Component or a bean.

Comment: this is the exception: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting '(' at character position 6
value =  @annotation(eu.genetwsiter.snpaware.annotation.TimePerformance)

Comment: Is the bean that has the `@TimePerformance` annotation declared in the same context?

Comment: What do you mean by context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the `execution(..)` in the pointcut expression?
I believe `@Around(value = @annotation(<full name of the class including the package>)")` should work. 
Because, you are saying by using the annotation,that, whichever method is annotated with this annotation needs to be inspected and the @Around advice invoked.

You wouldnt need the execution expression in my opinion because, even if your custom annotation can be applied to fields, Spring AOP doesnt support Aspects on fields.

Also, do you need to bind the object in the aspect? You can also get the object from `pjp.getArgs();` just in case.

**EDIT :**
Here is the Aspect

```
@Component(value = "regionAccessValidatorAspect")
@Aspect
public class RegionAccessValidatorAspect {

   @Around(value = "@annotation(com.....RegionAccessValidator)")
   public Object doAccessCheck(final ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
```

.....
}

Here is the processor on which i have setup my annotation

```
   @RegionAccessValidator(getVal = "Temporary")
   public CountryProductOfferingRepresentation update(final CountryProductOfferingRepresentation cpoRep,
         final RequestType requestType) throws Exception {
```

Here is the annotation

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RegionAccessValidator {

   String getVal();

}
```

Although, i havent tried by passing it an argument, i will try that today and find out if that is the cause.

Comment: As I said in the comment, using your syntax results in an exception fromat error

Comment: I dont neet the object, but the object is need to avoid the exception Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut annotation

Comment: I just tried an @Around advice with a setup similar to yours and it works perfectly fine for me. What i did notice in your question though is also that you do not have a space between the ( and the * in your pointcut expression. It should be execution( *, if you are using the execution expression that is